# What am I missing in Discord Bot that fetches new posts from users?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, discord.py

Bot is not working as intended.
It shows it's online in the console and Green Lit on Discord. And am not receiving any errors, although I am sure there is a disconnect somewhere.

It Seems to be Posting the very first post. Which Is made by the website and always stays there, Just need it to grab User Made posts instead.

Website I'm trying to Fetch new posts from: https://forum.cfx.re/c/development/releases/7

[The Post on my Discord.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMysT.png)

Here is a copy of my code  MINUS THE BOT TOKEN:

```
import asyncio
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import discord

# Discord bot token
BOT_TOKEN = ""

# Discord channel ID
CHANNEL_ID = "1106329342897827960"

# Global variable to store the previous post link
previous_post_link = None

async def check_for_updates():
    global previous_post_link

    try:
        url = "https://forum.cfx.re/c/development/releases/7"
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        new_post_link_element = soup.select_one("a.title.raw-link.raw-topic-link")
        if new_post_link_element:
            new_post_link = new_post_link_element["href"]

            if new_post_link != previous_post_link:
                # New post detected, send message to Discord channel
                channel = bot.get_channel(int(CHANNEL_ID))
                post_title = new_post_link_element.text.strip()
                message = f"New post: {post_title}\nLink: {new_post_link}"
                await channel.send(message)

                # Update previous post link
                previous_post_link = new_post_link

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while checking for updates: {str(e)}")

async def background_task():
    while True:
        await check_for_updates()
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Wait for 60 seconds before checking again

# Create a Discord bot instance
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})")
    print("------")

    # Start the background task
    await background_task()

# Run the bot
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(bot.start(BOT_TOKEN))
```

Comment: Then don't use `select_one`, which always picks the first.  Instead, use `select` and choose the second one (results[1]).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `new_post_link_element = soup.select_one("a.title.raw-link.raw-topic-link")`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? Specifically, what do you expect `select_one` to do? Did you try to check what the resulting `new_post_link_element` value is? Did you try to read the documentation? Why should this result change when the function is called again? Please read [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592.

Comment: It seems like you asked it to fetch the "first" post's information from the forum, and your intent is to check whether this is different from what you fetched last time, and if so make an update. However, it only ever shows you one post and never updates... did you notice which post it's showing you? It's the forum sticky, right? Can you think of a reason why this would always be the "first" post?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the `discord.ext.tasks` extension of discord.py and aiohttp, because your code is blocking the other processes in your program and the tasks extension is capable of making loops that can be customized (e.g. `seconds=60`)

Example:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

# The task you want to execute every minute
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def check_updates():
   # your code

# Starting the task in the bot.on_ready event
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   try:
      check_updates.start()
   except RuntimeError:
      pass # Do nothing when the task has already been created
      # This is because the on_ready event can be called more then one time in the lifespan 
      # of the program

# Start your bot
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Read the docs for more information about the tasks extension

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#